# How to calculate effective throughput from link speed, packet loss (%) and delay information?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ftp, tcp, vsftpd

I am working on a networks assignment where two linux VMs (say client and server) are connected by a bridge and I have to use ftp (vsftpd) to send a 100 MB file from client to server. I have set the link speed as 100 Mbps by setting the rate at both the interfaces that are connected by the bridge as 100 Mbit/s using tc command. Also, I set delay = 50ms and packet loss = 5% in **each direction.** using the tc command. Now I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the expected effective throughput or alternatively time taken for the file transfer so that I can compare it with the observed values and justify them.

In case of needing any further information, here are the images showing the rules added by the tc command: (both client and server have same rules)

[Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy9kG.png)

[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNcTk.png)

Comment: the latency (delay) shouldn't matter when you are interested in throughput, right? Just imagine a network when you first burn the data on CDs, load them on a truck and move them somewhere else. The latency could be several days but the throughput could still be super high :-D

Comment: @InnateImunityisTheWay But I am interested in effective/average throughput and not the throughput at an instant

Comment: Use iperf2/3 to get the actual rates between server and client. I use it to simulate QOS traffic all the time.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Yeah...but again it would be the observed rates. I want to estimate the rate myself based upon the above information

Comment: @DarkKnight 1) all the same, latency has nothing to do with throughput. My example with a truck loaded with CDs is exactly the average throughput. 2) so take the link speed, subtract the packet loss and you have the throughput.

Comment: @InnateImunityisTheWay By throughput I meant no. of bytes sent per second.

Comment: @DarkKnight me too. Yes, your definition is correct.